# DS-160: several employments and universities

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa

I am filling DS-160 form that I need to apply for F-1 student visa. Currently, I study at the double degree program between two universities and work part time (research and teaching assistanship positions associated with one of the universities).

DS-160 form allows for only one current occupation. What should I do in this regard? Is it a good idea to use one of the universities as a primary occupation and to list the other university and my employment in "were you previously employed" and "have you attended educational institutions at the secondary level or above" questions respectively? Or is it a bad idea to use these questions for the current occupations and I should use them for "truly" previous occupations only? Is it better to bring a full list of my extra current occupations with me to the interview without mentioning them in DS-160?